# Target iPhones, ipads and Android devices separately

Tags: css, media-queries

Is there any way to target iPhones, ipads and Android devices separately using CSS media queries?

Comment: No it is not possible. You can target different screen sizes but not different vendors. Why do you want to do that at all? Probably there is another solution.

Comment: Wanted to set separate font for ios only....

Comment: I don't think that there is another way then using js or that you deliver a different stylesheet depending on the useragent. For a js solution you might want to look on [CSS-TRICKS: OS Specific Fonts in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/os-specific-fonts-css/)

Answer (score 0):

You can always query for screen sizes, but not for separate OSs like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {...} // e.g. tablets
@media only screen and (max-width: 950px)  {...} // e.g. phablets
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px)  {...} // e.g. phones
```

If you need detection of browsers or operating systems, consider using a javascript library like [platform.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js/)

Comment: Thanks Tim.. I will try to solve the issue using this javascript library